# Cannot access all email signatures in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I have over 100 email signatures stored for use in Outlook 2007.

Why? I use them for canned responses. I realize there are probably better ways to do this, but this is easiest for me at this time.

**Problem:** After approx. 125 signatures in the list of signatures that appears in the drop-down list on the toolbar located on the message composition window, the text is not inserted into the body of the email when I click the desired signature.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of handling canned responses is to use [Quick Parts](http://www.timeatlas.com/mos/Email/Outlook/Reusing_Outlook_Text_and_Images/).  I'm surprised that there is a limitation to the number of signatures.  It's likely a bug that not many people would have run into.

Comment: There's no limitation on the number of signatures. In fact, I can see them all in the drop down list; however, when I select one close to the bottom of the list, the text is not inserted. It definitely must be a bug.

Comment: I agree with djhowell (gave him a vote), using Quick Parts is much easier. You don't have to create all of them at once, just when you use one signature, select it and add it to Quick Parts. I am pretty sure you will not get an answer very soon for this